# Spark add column to dataset according to time gap in timestamp

Tags: java, apache-spark, dataset

I have the following dataset:

```
    list.add(new SAMPLE("1", "2018-01-01 00:00:41.0"));
    list.add(new SAMPLE("1", "2018-01-01 00:01:12.0"));
    list.add(new SAMPLE("1", "2018-01-01 00:01:45.0"));
    list.add(new SAMPLE("1", "2018-01-01 00:04:00.0"));
    list.add(new SAMPLE("1", "2018-01-01 00:04:45.0"));

    list.add(new SAMPLE("2", "2018-01-01 00:00:41.0"));
    list.add(new SAMPLE("2", "2018-01-01 00:01:12.0"));
    list.add(new SAMPLE("2", "2018-01-01 00:01:21.0"));
    list.add(new SAMPLE("2", "2018-01-01 00:04:12.0"));
    list.add(new SAMPLE("2", "2018-01-01 00:04:35.0"));

    JavaRDD<SAMPLE> rdd = new JavaSparkContext(spark.sparkContext()).parallelize(list);
    Dataset<Row> dataset = spark.createDataset(rdd.rdd(), Encoders.bean(SAMPLE.class)).toDF();
```

I want to add column (newColumn) to this dataset based on time gap equal to (2 minutes), so if i have any gap (>= 2 minutes) then the next items should have different value in the new column.

So the new dataset will look like the following:

```
    "1", "2018-01-01 00:00:41.0" , i1
    "1", "2018-01-01 00:01:12.0" , i1
    "1", "2018-01-01 00:01:45.0" , i1

    "1", "2018-01-01 00:04:00.0" , i2
    "1", "2018-01-01 00:04:45.0" , i2

    "2", "2018-01-01 00:00:41.0" , i1
    "2", "2018-01-01 00:01:12.0" , i1
    "2", "2018-01-01 00:01:21.0" , i1

    "2", "2018-01-01 00:04:12.0" , i2
    "2", "2018-01-01 00:04:35.0" , i2
```

I there anyway to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I try your scenario with "mapPartitions" method and i can getting the which you want to the result. Firstly, if you want perform this operation for every id, you must transform this rdd to "pair rdd". And after, foreach in "ids", you can perform this code.

```
mapPartitions(new FlatMapFunction<Iterator<Row>, Row>(){

        @Override
        public Iterator<Row> call(Iterator<Row> t) throws Exception {
            List<Row> list = new ArrayList<Row>();
            Integer last = 0;
            while(t.hasNext()) {
                Row current = t.next();
                list.add(RowFactory.create(current.get(0), current.get(1), last > 0 ? (current.getInt(1) - last) : 1)); // in this line new column (difference) has been insert to dataset
                last = current.getInt(1);
            }
            return list.iterator();
        }

    })
```

And here i work with integer values those can taking difference operation. You must change this line with your function. Like calculate the difference between two dates.

Comment: thanks  it worked for me! 
I did not have to convert to JavaPair, I directly used MapFunction on my dataset.

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can do is write a small spark UDF. Its quite simple actually

```
session.udf().register("UDFNAME", new UDF1<String, String>() {

        @Override
        public String call(String date) throws Exception {
            /* your logic to calculate minute diff */
            return value;
        }
    }, DataTypes.StringType);
```

this will register your udf with the current spark session, then you can call your udf as below

```
dataset.withColumn("NewColumnNameInYouTable", callUDF("UDFNAME", col("ColumnOnWhichYouWantToCallUDF"))).write().saveAsTable("TableName");
```

withColumn method helps you add a new column to your dataset, it takes 2 arguments the columnname you want to give to your new column and the Column itself, here we are generating the coulmn by calling the registered UDF and at last creating that dataset as a table (if that is your requirement).

One more thing, the above is just an example, the params and return type of UDF can change as per your requirement.

Hope it helps!!!!

Comment: I don't think UDF would help without using WindowSpec  to detect the time gap (2 minutes) .
For now I think I should use WindowSpec and RowsBetween(-1,0) to detect the gap but then I'm confused how to continue!

Answer (score 0):

I have used Scala here but it should be easily reproducible in Java since I am using DataFrame functions.

```scala
//Creating a timestamp based window of 2 minutes.
//Count is performed to materialize the window since aggreation is required with group by
val grouped = df.groupBy($"id" , window($"ts" , "2 minutes")).count

//+---+---------------------------------------------+-----+
//|id |window                                       |count|
//+---+---------------------------------------------+-----+
//|2  |[2018-01-01 00:00:00.0,2018-01-01 00:02:00.0]|3    |
//|1  |[2018-01-01 00:00:00.0,2018-01-01 00:02:00.0]|3    |
//|1  |[2018-01-01 00:04:00.0,2018-01-01 00:06:00.0]|2    |
//|2  |[2018-01-01 00:04:00.0,2018-01-01 00:06:00.0]|2    |
//+---+---------------------------------------------+-----+

//Then using Window functions to generate a rank based on id partition

import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window
val rankedDf = grouped.withColumn("rank" , 
                                   concat(lit("i") ,
                                   rank.over(Window.partitionBy($"id").orderBy($"window".asc)))
                                 )
                      .select($"*", $"window.*").drop("window", "count")

rankedDf.show
+---+----+-------------------+-------------------+
| id|rank|              start|                end|
+---+----+-------------------+-------------------+
|  1|  i1|2018-01-01 00:00:00|2018-01-01 00:02:00|
|  1|  i2|2018-01-01 00:04:00|2018-01-01 00:06:00|
|  2|  i1|2018-01-01 00:00:00|2018-01-01 00:02:00|
|  2|  i2|2018-01-01 00:04:00|2018-01-01 00:06:00|
+---+----+-------------------+-------------------+


// Joining it with the original dataframe
 df.as("l").join(res18.as("r") , $"l.id" === $"r.id" &&
                                 $"l.ts".between($"r.start", $"r.end"))
           .select("l.id", "l.ts", "r.rank")
           .show(false)

//+---+-------------------+----+
//| id|                 ts|rank|
//+---+-------------------+----+
//|  1|2018-01-01 00:00:41|  i1|
//|  1|2018-01-01 00:01:12|  i1|
//|  1|2018-01-01 00:01:45|  i1|
//|  1|2018-01-01 00:04:00|  i2|
//|  1|2018-01-01 00:04:45|  i2|
//|  2|2018-01-01 00:00:41|  i1|
//|  2|2018-01-01 00:01:12|  i1|
//|  2|2018-01-01 00:01:21|  i1|
//|  2|2018-01-01 00:04:12|  i2|
//|  2|2018-01-01 00:04:35|  i2|
//+---+-------------------+----+
```